# My question was incorrectly marked as a duplicate. Can this be reviewed again?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, question-closure, duplicates

I believe there is a clear difference between my question and the question marked as a duplicate. I have edited the post to emphasize how it is different, now I'm posting here to see if someone can review it again.

My question: [Where did the practice of using quotation marks to discredit an opponent ("scare-quotes") come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225523/where-did-the-practice-of-using-quotation-marks-to-discredit-an-opponent-scare)

*META*: I generally don't trust people who complain on Meta Stack Exchange sites about stuff like this, but I believe my case is pretty strong here. It might be that I didn't communicate clearly enough, but I'm positive that the question that I'm trying to ask is *not* the same.

Comment: I agree with you (and I appreciate your meta-commentary). I have voted to re-open.

Comment: I also appreciate your meta post. I can't retract my close vote, but I've voted to reopen as well. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks everyone, and note I don't take downvotes or close votes personally. :)

Comment: Bravo for editing the question to highlight the difference; that's a very constructive way to handle this situation.